Jekyll Theme Minima not displaying correctly on Github Pages?
This is my first time doing somthing like this, so I'm not sure where I've got wrong.
When I was building it and checking locally, all looked good. Now I've tried to deploy on Github Pages and all the styling is gone. I am using the jekyll theme minima and followed the instructions. I did make some minor, minor adjustments to the css, which is why it is copied into the folder.
Edit removed the link to the repo as problem fixed

I found the answer here after some more searching.
Comment out baseurl: "" in _config.yaml
